# I want to capture the starting and end point of all the series in my multigraph and show it in a table using MeasureX of StockTools in Highstock

Tags: highcharts

I have a MultiGraph i.e a graph with multiple series. What I want to do is use MeasureX(stockTools GUI Button) to highlight a particular area in my graph and then display the starting and end point of all the series in that highlighted area in a separate table inside my widget. How can I achieve that? If anyone can tell me atleast how can I capture the MeasureX event in my code with the required value, I can take it forward from there. My series look something like this.

Series:[{type:line,data:[],name:X},{type:line,data:[],name:Y},{type:line,data:[],name:Z}.....],

P.S: Please let me know if I can help with some other clarifications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `end` event for the `measureX` bindings, example:

```
navigation: {
  bindings: {
    measureX: {
      end: function(e, annotation) {
        var x1 = annotation.startXMin,
          x2 = annotation.startXMax,
          series = annotation.chart.series[0],
          filteredPoints = series.points.filter(
            point => point.x > x1 && point.x < x2
          ),
          firstPoint = filteredPoints[0],
          lastPoint = filteredPoints[filteredPoints.length - 1];

        firstPoint.graphic.attr({
          stroke: 'red'
        });
        lastPoint.graphic.attr({
          stroke: 'red'
        });
      }
    }
  }
}
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/b4u7ehjo/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/navigation.bindings.measureX

Comment: Thanks for your response. Your solution is correct for single line graph i.e contains only one object in series, however in my case it is a multiline graph which have multiple series objects as shown in my question above. my question is how will I capture the startXMin and startXMax of all my series object in that selected area? @ppotaczek

Comment: Hi @Nishit, Use the same approach, but just loop through the series: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/Ld5xvey4/

Comment: Thanks, You idea really helped me in implementing my Logic.  However, I want to ask is there any event which gets triggered in readjusting the highlighted range? What I want to say is once I highlight a particular area, then end event is triggered but when I readjust the same area, end event is not getting triggered. Is there any separate event for that? I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: Hello, the `afterUpdate` event should help in this case, example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/d39fz8tg/

Comment: Thanks @ppotaczek. I was using annotations.events.afterupdate. Which was not working.

Comment: Did you check the last example? Everything seems to be working fine there.